# How to copy file with fixed name from a folder on which last folder name in folder path is unknown?

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem on copying a file because of name of one directory in directory tree varies.

The directory tree is: **D:\folder\***Unknown Folder***\myfile.rar**

I want to copy the RAR file inside **D:\folder\** containing only one folder.

The name of this folder varies and is therefore unknown for me.

I want that the batch script opens **D:\folder\**, then find and open first subfolder and finally copies the RAR file **myfile.rar**.

Something like this:

```
 copy "D:\folder\*\myfile.rar" "D:\a.rar"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each folder under `d:\folder`, if the searched file exists, copy to target folder

```
for /d %%a in ("d:\folder\*") do if exist "%%a\myfile.rar" copy "%%a\myfile.rar" d:\a.rar
```

To use it from command line, replace all `%%` with `%`

Answer (score 1):

copy does not support wildcards in the path.

MC ND's answer is good enough , but you can try also this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "D:/folder/" ^|findstr /i /e /c:"/myfile.rar"') do (
   copy "%%a" d:\a.rar
)
```